# Where is the location of my sqlite database file?

Tags: c, sqlite

I have created a database in C by using sqlite. Here is code:

```
int x = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);
```

`argv[1]` is a argument which contains the name of database. I think that the database should be stored in a file which ends with .db, but I am unable to find that file.

Where can I find the mentioned file (file with structure of database etc ...)?

Comment: What is the contents of `argv[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

The file will be created wherever your path specified, or wherever the program was running from (e.g. your `C:\Users\User Name` directory).

It has not necessarily a `.db` extension, that is: you can create a file named however you want. If you need to find it, maybe you can try looking for files created in a given time interval.

Your best option is to always specify a full path, and create files with the .sqlite or .db extension.

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3_open is defined as

```
int sqlite3_open(
   const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
   sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
```

so the database is called whatever you put in the first argument was.  the .db suffix will not be added automagically.

As for the directory the file was stored in, if you specified an absolute path in argv[1](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html) that's where the file will be stored, if not it should be in the current working directory.

If you **really** need that file back and it's not where you expect it to be, nor does it have a .db extension (because you forgot to specify it) and you can't remember the name you gave there's one last possibility: see the [sqlite file format specification](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html), a sqlite file always starts with "SQLite format 3\000" (a null terminated string).

```
find / -exec grep -l "SQLite format 3" {} \;
```

This will print name & path of all files containing that string, but that command will take some time...

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3_open` is documented as creating the database, but SQLite will not actually create the file until you do any changes to the database.

Create a table to ensure that the file will be created.

Answer (score -1):

I you are using Linux you can use the "locate "command on the terminal like this

```
locate *.db
```

in the / directory . You will get the location

Comment: I think this locate command might be helpful to you .. You can use find command also to find any file .. anyway you havn't mentioned about your operating system

Comment: As [locate depends on the freshness of its database](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?locate+1) and updatedb typically runs overnight he will have to wait until tomorrow to find his file :-)  In the mean time he can use [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)

Comment: It is best to quote the argument (`locate '*.db'`), or you risk finding the wrong files. For example if you do this in a directory containing test.db, the shell will send to locate the expanded name, 'test.db', and your "locate test.db" command will not find all .db files, but only those called *exactly* `test.db`.

Comment: @fvu, on Linux he can wait a few minutes while running a manually-launched `updatedb`. Or he can use `find PATH_FROM_WHERE_TO_START -type f -name '*.db'`.

Comment: I have also said about the "find" in my previous comment

Comment: @lserni assuming of course the file name ends in db, and I'm willing to bet that that's not the case here - see my answer.  And the downvote isn't mine btw.

Comment: @fvu I'd bet the same :-) (mine neither)